# Facebook decoded signed_request contains extra data which isn't mentioned in the documentation

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a Facebook `signed_request` which is received by subscribing to the `auth.login` event  and after the user logs in using the [facebook login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)

After I decode the `signed_request` I have the following information in it:

```
{'issued_at': 1318492701, 
'code': 'AQCXI5aiyYtYLFNtkYhtKwDhO02lP[truncated]', 
'user_id': '100000xxxxxxxxx', 
'algorithm': 'HMAC-SHA256'}
```

I cannot find in the [signed_request documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). What is this `code` and what's its use?

I thought it might be used to obtain an authorization code as stated in [this thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=71906) but along with the `signed_request` I also receive an access token for the user in the response from the login event.

Comment: This is the signed_request from the JavaScript SDK, right?
The code is used by the SDK but isn't for the Server-side Authentication. It is not documented as this is not useful for Authentication.

Comment: Indeed, I get the code from the authResponse signed request I get when I get the user login status, amongst others.

Comment: @yoshi i request you please check my answer thanks

Comment: Facebook stuff is broken an undocumented?!  *gasp*

Comment: @Alexandre Couturon: Please post your previous comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the signed_request from the JavaScript SDK, right? The code is used by the SDK but isn't for the Server-side Authentication. Actually, we will update the documentation to reflect the signed_request behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why they don't mention use of the code on the documentation page for signed requests.  The code can be exchanged for an access token that is the key to making any subsequent Facebook API requests.

Relevant documentation is here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> With this code in hand, you can proceed to the next step, app authentication, to gain the access token you need to make API calls.
>
> In order to authenticate your app, you must pass the authorization code and your app secret to the Graph API token endpoint - along with the exact same redirect_uri used above - at https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. The app secret is available from the Developer App and should not be shared with anyone or embedded in any code that you will distribute (you should use the client-side flow for these scenarios).

Comment: That's what I thought at first but if I try to use that code to get an access token I always get an OAuth exception saying that the code cannot be validated. And the format of the code is different as well, it has two or three periods in it as where the codes that are not inside the signed_request don't have the periods and is somewhat longer.

Comment: @yoshi nice reply again and again ;)

Comment: @Danish Iqbal: already saw it, it has no new information relevant to my question as the information I'm looking for is not covered by the documentation. Been over it a couple of times and haven't seen any "code" parameter mentioned inside the signedRequest received from the auth.login response.

Answer (score 1):

that code is useful to get information about users who installed your app

but anyway tell me which information is needed for you then i can give you sample code

---

well, if you check your posted code again you see you have user id 
so you do not need to use access token for this

but anyway for getting basic information & any other information or posting & deleting you have two ways :

first:do it directly (no need to sdk,but harder)
second: via sdk (its easy)
i recommend to you to use sdk & if your server side programming language is PHP you can do this for getting basic information

```
    <?php
    include_once ('src/facebook.php');/// include sdk
    ////// config The sdk
        @ $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '*************',
        'secret' => '*****************',
         )); 
$user=$facebook->api('me','GET');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

for downloading 
download php sdk

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: How do you use it to get which users have got the app installed? I haven't seen anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: I'm using Python so that's not really helpful. I know how to get the user info, I just want to know what `code` from INSIDE the signed request is for.

Comment: that code is your key to get user info if you try to get data directly
you need access token (for example for current user) 
 from urls like this https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=THE CODE YOU GET

Comment: Nope, the code is not an access token. I get the access token separately. The JS SDK returns the authResponse with a signed request and access token. Inside the signed request there's the `code`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to visit this [facebook offical doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) and read "signed_request Parameter" and its below text for the code which you get after decoding `signed_request`

Comment: please see the fb offical doc link in my above answer thanks :)